# Going from (a_1, a_2, ..., a_n) to (f(a_1), f(a_2), ..., f(a_n))

Tags: python

Support given a list `(a_1, a_2, ..., a_n)` and a function `f`.

What is the pythonic way of producing `(f(a_1), f(a_2), ..., f(a_n))`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Either

```
map(f, my_list)
```

or

```
[f(x) for x in my_list]
```

Answer (score 3):

Using [`map()`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#map):

```
data = (a_1, a_2, ..., a_n)
results = map(f, data)
```

Or with a [list comprehension](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions):

```
results = [f(x) for x in data]
```

Answer (score 1):

Lists in Python are delimited by brackets, not parentheses... assuming that's what you meant:

```
[f(a) for a in a_list]
```

If you actually meant to create a tuple, which is the thing that is delimited by parentheses, you can do this:

```
tuple(f(a) for a in a_list)
```

A tuple can be thought of as an immutable list.

It is also possible to create a generator, which is something different. A generator can be used in a `for` loop, and it creates its elements one at a time, as they are needed, rather than creating them all at once as a list comprehension (the first code sample in this answer) does.

```
g = (f(a) for a in a_list)
for x in g:
    # do stuff
```

I have a feeling that's not what you meant to do here, though.

Comment: Ah, I want to work with bracket objects. What are they called?

Comment: (1,2,3) is a "tuple", [1,2,3] is a "list".